# How does NumPy control the behavior of native number types' methods?

Tags: python, numpy, methods, overriding

How does NumPy accomplish this?

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 1 + np.array([1])
array([2])
```

I understand how it works with the operands in the opposite order:

```py
>>> class Adder():
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             return 'what I will'
...
>>> Adder() + 1
'what I will'
```

But it appears the first way call's the `__add__` method in `int`:

```py
>>> class Adder():
...     def _add__(self, other):
...             return 'what I want'
...
>>> 1 + Adder()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Adder'
```

I couldn't find anything in the source. How do they do it?

Comment: The numpy classes will implement `__radd__` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=radd#object.__radd__ *"These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types"*

Comment: Missed that! Thanks to both slothrop and mkrieger1, I get it now.